# how to check sql injection and other php vulnerability in my site?

Tags: sql-injection, csrf, xss

how do i check sql injection, XSS, and CSRF in my php site ? for example i have a pages like viewentry.php?id=3 How to check such pages ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SQL injection scanner](http://maestro-sec.com/blogs/2008/10/top-15-sql-injection-scanner/).

There is also [JAASCOIS Anti Web-Injection](http://www.bujarra.com/descargas/JAAScoisAWIen.rar).